# Is it "making a ripple" or "creating a ripple"?

Tags: word-choice

So, I'm preparing for a PTE test and came across this problem in the **Fill in the Blanks** section.

> Gators can move through the water oh so silently, barely ___
> (making/creating/adding/showing) a ripple.

Why is the answer creating the ripple (not *making the ripple*) here? I just wanted to know the reasoning behind selecting the word "creating" instead of "making".

Comment: Note the more and more common “send ripples”. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=make+ripples%2C+send+ripples&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the test is wrong. [Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22barely+making+a+ripple%22&lr=lang_en&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1891%2Ccd_max%3A2009%2Clr%3Alang_1en&tbm=bks&sxsrf=APwXEdfWpDIgEkx_2H-oaAgj9b_1rP-Y-Q%3A1683779420808&ei=XG9cZM_tMK2u5NoPvJKgmAs&oq=%22barely+making+a+ripple%22) turns up plenty of examples of this usage of "barely making a ripple."

[Here's a similar example from UNSW:](https://www.unsw.edu.au/research/cmsi/research-projects/integrated-micro-macro-biology-and-ecology/wake-interference-swimming-crocodiles)

> Crocodiles, including the saltwater crocodile (Crocodylus porosus), have the remarkable ability to swim underwater at high speed while **barely making a ripple** at the surface.

Comment: And you can compare making a noise, making a pattern, making a mark...